# How to publish JSON data into Kafka? Here the my JSON data in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a data in a CSV file that I converted into JSON as dataframe like 
`val jsondata =  sampleDF.toJSON`.

Trying to publish data into kafka as follows:

```
val message = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("topicsample", null, jsondata)
```

Getting string manupation error. How can I handle this?

Comment: Stringify the JSON

Comment: Do you mean "manipulation"?

Comment: Could you please show your dataframe?

Comment: jsondata: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, end_date: string ... 2 more fields]
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- end_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- location: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of exception and your code?

Comment: //kafka code
val topics = Array("test")
val kafkaBrokers = "10.190.29.546:9092"
/***Publish to kafka/
val data = inputDF.toJSON  -- Convert the JSON data into rdd
val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBrokers)
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

Comment: val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
val message = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("test",  data)     
producer.send(message)